# Nexus Unable to connect with repos on the Internet

Tags: maven, nexus

I set up a nexus server locally and updated my local settings.xml to point it. Now whenever I run maven clean or package commands, it does not download the dependencies and throws the following error.

> Return code is: 502 , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Error ( Connection refused )

But when I update my local settings.xml to not to point to nexus server, it downloads all jars locally and works fine. I think, this has to do with nexus not being able to connect with outside world. Where I can set our company's proxy settings in Nexus. I have tried setting proxy under

> Application Server Settings

but had no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @EngineerDollery It's Windows7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm that Nexus can connect to e.g. the Central Repository by trying to browse the remote repository of Central. If that doesnt work your proxy server, firewall or something else is blocking Nexus from getting out.

If thats the case you have to fix your proxy settings in Nexus in Administration - Server.